# Error when fetching information from API on phone

Tags: python, request, kivy, buildozer, urllib3

I'm trying to build my kivy app. It works good on my computer, but when it comes to phone this problem with urllib appears:

```
    def Anime_Search(self):

        request = Request('https://kitsu.io/api/edge', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

        headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json'
        }

        url = 'https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime?filter[text]=' + str(anime2)

        request = requests.request("GET", url=url, headers=headers)
        anime = request.json()

        poster = anime['data'][0]['attributes']['posterImage']['medium']

        r = requests.get(poster, stream=True, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open("img.jpg", 'wb') as f:
                r.raw.decode_content = True
                shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='kitsu.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/edge/anime?filter[text]=naruto (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xcc4c3810>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname'))
```

I would appriciate all help.

Comment: Are you able to provide some sample code? without the code, we won't know what is causing the error to help you.

Comment: ok I edited post

Answer (score 2):

Setting this in buildozer.spec helped:

```
# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET
```